# OCPP 1.6 Remote Start Transaction

Tags: python, ocpp

This is our CentralSystem.py

We have a LIVE charger configured to connect to our websocket
Ex - ws://HostName:Port/Charger Serial Number

As soon as the Charger is connected to our central system, it automatically sends us the following:

Charge point /D5200372001000010101 connected
INFO:ocpp:D5200372001000010101: receive message [2,"530","Heartbeat",{}]
Heartbeat
INFO:ocpp:D5200372001000010101: send [3,"530",{"currentTime":"2022-06-10T10:43:26Z"}]
INFO:ocpp:D5200372001000010101: receive message [2,"531","Heartbeat",{}]
Heartbeat

Issue 1 - We receive the heartbeat every 2mins but do not see anything for BootNotification and Status Notification when no vehicle is connected.

However, when the vehicle is connected, we do see a Status Notification and Heartbeats.

Issue 2 - Now, we have a mobile app that is built using Flutter which should allow us to enable "Remote Start Transaction". What is the best way to achieve this? Should we connect to the same websocket endpoint and call RemoteStartTransaction.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from asyncio import constants

import websockets
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from ocpp.routing import on
from ocpp.v16 import ChargePoint as cp
from ocpp.v16.enums import Action, RegistrationStatus, RemoteStartStopStatus
import ocpp.v16.enums as enums
from ocpp.v16 import call_result, call
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class ChargePoint(cp):
  chargingProfile = {}

  @on(Action.RemoteStartTransaction)
  async def on_remote_start(self, id_tag, connector_id):
    print("remotely starting")
    return await self.remote_start_transaction()

  @on(Action.BootNotification)
  def on_boot_notification(self, charge_point_vendor, charge_point_model, **kwargs):
    print("Boot Notification")
    return call_result.BootNotificationPayload(
      # current_time=datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z',
      current_time=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + "Z",
      interval=100,
      status=RegistrationStatus.accepted
    )

  @on(Action.StatusNotification)
  def on_status_notification(self, connector_id, error_code, status, **kwargs):
    print("Status Notification")
    return call_result.StatusNotificationPayload()

  @on(Action.Heartbeat)
  def on_heartbeat(self):
    print("Heartbeat")
    return call_result.HeartbeatPayload(
      current_time=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + "Z"
    )

  @on(Action.Authorize)
  def on_authorize(self, id_tag):
    print("Authorize")
    query = {'access_token': 'masterKey'}

    response = requests.get('http://ec2-13-233-102-233.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/chargersOnboarding/',
                            params=query)
    data = response.json()
    isFound = "false"
    status = ""

    for item in data['rows']:
      if item['RFID'] == id_tag:
        isFound = "true"
        if item['status'] == 0:
          status = "Accepted"
        else:
          status = "Expired"
        break
      else:
        continue
    if isFound == "true":
      print("Authorized")
      return call_result.AuthorizePayload(
        id_tag_info={
          # "expiryDate": "2022-02-04T13:00:00.21Z",
          "expiryDate": "2023-05-19T13:00:00.21Z",
          "parentIdTag": id_tag,
          "status": status
        },
      )
    else:
      print("Not Authorized")
      return call_result.AuthorizePayload(
        id_tag_info={
          "expiryDate": "",
          "parentIdTag": id_tag,
          "status": "Invalid"
        },
      )

  @on(Action.StartTransaction)
  def on_start_transaction(self, connector_id, id_tag, meter_start, timestamp, **kwargs):
    print("START TRANSACTION COMING FROM CHARGER")
    query = {'access_token': 'masterKey'}

    response = requests.get('http://ec2-13-233-102-233.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/chargersOnboarding/',
                            params=query)
    data = response.json()
    isFound = "false"
    status = ""

    for item in data['rows']:
      if item['RFID'] == id_tag:
        isFound = "true"
        if item['status'] == 0:
          status = "Accepted"
        else:
          status = "Expired"
        break
      else:
        continue
    if isFound == "true":
      return call_result.StartTransactionPayload(
        id_tag_info={
          # "expiryDate": "2022-02-04T13:00:00.21Z",
          "expiryDate": "2023-05-19T13:00:00.21Z",
          "parentIdTag": id_tag,
          "status": status
        },
        transaction_id=int(1)
      )
    else:
      print("Not Authorized")
      return call_result.StartTransactionPayload(
        id_tag_info={
          "expiryDate": "",
          "parentIdTag": id_tag,
          "status": "Invalid"
        },
        transaction_id=int(1)
      )

  @on(Action.StopTransaction)
  def on_stop_transaction(self, transaction_id, timestamp, meter_stop, id_tag, **kwargs):
    query = {'access_token': 'masterKey'}
    response = requests.get('http://ec2-13-233-102-233.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/chargersOnboarding/',
                            params=query)
    data = response.json()
    isFound = "false"
    status = ""

    for item in data['rows']:
      if item['RFID'] == id_tag:
        isFound = "true"
        if item['status'] == 0:
          status = "Accepted"
        else:
          status = "Expired"
        break
      else:
        continue
    if isFound == "true":
      return call_result.StopTransactionPayload(
        id_tag_info={
          # "expiryDate": "2022-02-04T13:00:00.21Z",
          "expiryDate": "2023-05-19T13:00:00.21Z",
          "parentIdTag": id_tag,
          "status": status
        },
        # transaction_id=int(1)
      )
    else:
      print("Not Authorized")
      return call_result.StopTransactionPayload(
        id_tag_info={
          "expiryDate": "",
          "parentIdTag": id_tag,
          "status": "Invalid"
        },
        transaction_id=int(1)
      )

  @on(Action.MeterValues)
  def on_meter_value(self, **kwargs):
    return call_result.MeterValuesPayload()

  @on(Action.DataTransfer)
  def on_data_transfer(self, vendor_id, message_id, data):
    return call_result.DataTransferPayload(
      status='Accepted'
    )

  @on(Action.ChangeAvailability)
  def on_change_availabilty(self, connector_id, type):
    return call_result.ChangeAvailabilityPayload(
      status='Accepted'
    )

  async def send_limitation(self, limit):
    response = await self.call(call.SetChargingProfilePayload(
      connector_id=0,
      cs_charging_profiles={
        'chargingProfileId': 1,
        'stackLevel': 0,
        'chargingProfilePurpose': enums.ChargingProfilePurposeType.chargepointmaxprofile,
        'chargingProfileKind': enums.ChargingProfileKindType.absolute,
        'chargingSchedule': {
          'startSchedule': datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + "Z",
          'chargingRateUnit': enums.ChargingRateUnitType.amps,
          'chargingSchedulePeriod': [{
            'startPeriod': 0,
            'limit': limit
          }]
        }
      }
    ))
    print("SEND Limitation")
    print(response)

  async def remote_start_transaction(self):
    obj = {
      'chargingProfileId': 1,
      'stackLevel': 0,
      'chargingProfilePurpose': enums.ChargingProfilePurposeType.chargepointmaxprofile,
      'chargingProfileKind': enums.ChargingProfileKindType.absolute,
      'chargingSchedule': {
        'startSchedule': datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + "Z",
        'chargingRateUnit': enums.ChargingRateUnitType.amps,
        'chargingSchedulePeriod': [{
          'startPeriod': 0,
          'limit': 8.0
        }]
      },

    }
    print("REMOTE START!!!")
    request = call.RemoteStartTransactionPayload(
      id_tag='5C1DEA5A',
      charging_profile=obj,
      connector_id=1
    )
    response = await self.call(request)
    print(response)
    if response.status == RemoteStartStopStatus.accepted:
      print("Transaction Started!!!")
    else:
      print("Transaction Failed to Start!!!")
      print(response.status)
      # websockets.send("Transaction Started!!!")

  async def remote_stop_transaction(self):
    print("REMOTE STOP!!!")
    request = call.RemoteStopTransactionPayload(
      transaction_id=1
    )
    response = await self.call(request)

    if response.status == RemoteStartStopStatus.accepted:
      print("Stopping transaction")
      # websockets.send("Transaction Stopped!!!")


async def on_connect(websocket, path):

  charge_point_id = path.strip('/')
  cp = ChargePoint(charge_point_id, websocket)
  try:
    print(f'Charge point {path} connected')
    await asyncio.gather(cp.start())

  except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
    print(f"Charge Point {path} disconnected")


async def main():
  server = await websockets.serve(
    on_connect,
    '0.0.0.0',
    9000,
    subprotocols=['ocpp1.6'],
    ping_interval=None,
    ping_timeout=None

  )

  logging.info("Server Started listening to new connections...")
  await server.wait_closed()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: in the on_connect, you are writing `charge_point_path` in one line and `charge_point_id` in the next line.  maybe in your environment exceptions/errors are not getting logged.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I was formatting the file. I have edited the code. But, no that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
> async def send_heartbeat(self, interval):
>         request = call.HeartbeatPayload()
>         while True:
>             await self.call(request)
>             await asyncio.sleep(interval)
> 

> await asyncio.gather(cp.start(), cp.send_heartbeat(10))
```

Comment: Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).